# Cannot make BigInt class working in Visual C++

Tags: c++, bigint

I am trying to representing a 128-bit number in Visual C++, which direct me to the library [BigInt class](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/). 
Many people mentioned it, so I think its a well known library.

When I try to run its main example, I got a long error list. Seem like something missing.

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual __thiscall BigInt::BaseBigInt::~BaseBigInt(void)" (??1BaseBigInt@BigInt@@MAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall BigInt::Rossi::~Rossi(void)" (??1Rossi@BigInt@@UAE@XZ)    c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class BigInt::Rossi const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABVRossi@BigInt@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl demoBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?demoBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@@Z)   c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall BigInt::Rossi::Rossi(void)" (??0Rossi@BigInt@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl demoBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?demoBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@@Z) c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall BigInt::Rossi::Rossi(unsigned __int64)" (??0Rossi@BigInt@@QAE@_K@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl demoBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?demoBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@@Z)   c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall BigInt::Rossi::Rossi(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int)" (??0Rossi@BigInt@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@I@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl demoBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?demoBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@@Z)    c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long double __thiscall BigInt::Rossi::toDouble(void)const " (?toDouble@Rossi@BigInt@@QBEOXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl simpleDemoBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (?simpleDemoBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)  c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class BigInt::Rossi __cdecl BigInt::Rossi::fromDouble(long double const &)" (?fromDouble@Rossi@BigInt@@SA?AV12@ABO@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl simpleDemoBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (?simpleDemoBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)  c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class BigInt::Rossi __thiscall BigInt::Rossi::operator+(class BigInt::Rossi const &)" (??HRossi@BigInt@@QAE?AV01@ABV01@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl demoBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?demoBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@@Z)   c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   9   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class BigInt::Rossi __thiscall BigInt::Rossi::operator*(class BigInt::Rossi)const " (??DRossi@BigInt@@QBE?AV01@V01@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl demoBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?demoBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@@Z)   c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   10  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class BigInt::Rossi __thiscall BigInt::Rossi::operator/(class BigInt::Rossi const &)const " (??KRossi@BigInt@@QBE?AV01@ABV01@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl demoBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?demoBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@@Z) c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   11  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class BigInt::Rossi __thiscall BigInt::Rossi::sqrt(void)" (?sqrt@Rossi@BigInt@@QAE?AV12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl demoBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?demoBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@@Z)  c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   12  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class BigInt::Rossi __cdecl BigInt::Rossi::pow(class BigInt::Rossi const &,class BigInt::Rossi const &,bool)" (?pow@Rossi@BigInt@@SA?AV12@ABV12@0_N@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl simpleDemoBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (?simpleDemoBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z) c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   13  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall BigInt::Rossi::toStr0xHex(void)const " (?toStr0xHex@Rossi@BigInt@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl simpleDemoBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (?simpleDemoBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)   c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   14  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall BigInt::Rossi::toStrDec(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)const " (?toStrDec@Rossi@BigInt@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV34@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl demoBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?demoBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@@Z) c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   15  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned int __thiscall BigInt::Rossi::getActualHexDigits(void)const " (?getActualHexDigits@Rossi@BigInt@@UBEIXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl simpleDemoBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (?simpleDemoBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z) c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   16  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned int __thiscall BigInt::Rossi::getActualDecDigits(void)const " (?getActualDecDigits@Rossi@BigInt@@UBEIXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl simpleDemoBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (?simpleDemoBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z) c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   17  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl BigInt::Run::mainBigInt(int,char * *)" (?mainBigInt@Run@BigInt@@SAHHPAPAD@Z) referenced in function _main c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   18  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl BigInt::Run::showTime(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?showTime@Run@BigInt@@SAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@4@@Z) referenced in function _main  c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   19  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl BigInt::Run::showCommandLine(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,int,char * *)" (?showCommandLine@Run@BigInt@@SAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@HPAPAD@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl showIllegalCommandLineBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,int,char * *)" (?showIllegalCommandLineBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@HPAPAD@Z) c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   20  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl BigInt::Run::showHelp(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?showHelp@Run@BigInt@@SAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@4@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl demoBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?demoBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@@Z)   c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   21  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl BigInt::Test::setTestName(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?setTestName@Test@BigInt@@SAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@4@1III@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl demoBigInt(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?demoBigInt@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@@Z)    c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   22  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const BigInt::s_strHelp" (?s_strHelp@BigInt@@2V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@B)    c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   23  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const BigInt::s_strDemo" (?s_strDemo@BigInt@@2V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@B)    c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   24  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const BigInt::s_strTest" (?s_strTest@BigInt@@2V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@B)    c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   25  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const BigInt::s_strTime" (?s_strTime@BigInt@@2V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@B)    c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
Error   26  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned int BigInt::Test::s_returnValue" (?s_returnValue@Test@BigInt@@2IA)   c:\Users\HyNguyen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestBinInt\TestBinInt\Source.obj    TestBinInt
```

Comment: In Visual C++ it is not enough to `#include` the header, the respective library .lib file must be specified for the linker, in the project settings. It can also be specified in the code, by using `#pragma comment(lib, "libfile.lib")`

Comment: I looked at the doc. Did you add `bigInt.cpp` to your project?

Comment: @Havena: I can't find any .lib file of this libray, just a bigint.cpp and bigint.h

Comment: @lakeweb: I copy both bigint.cpp and bigint.h to my project, and included bigint.h

Comment: OK, I fixed the problem. In Visual Studio, I added the bigint.cpp to "Resource Files", and add bigint.h to "Header Files", then I only have to add _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS and _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNIGS, and everything work.

Comment: @Andiana -- That doesn't sound like a solution -- it sounds like there are serious issues with the setup of this code.  Adding a C++ source file to the resources makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, PaulMcKenzie is right. You got a way with it, just how VS works. But you should have drug it to the 'source files' BTW, I've used InfInt for big ints. Header only, and it works great.

Comment: Those are just virtual folders, what really determine what each thing is its extension. But .cpp files should go to Source files and .h to header files